# Spree - Spree_Paypal_Express - superclass must be a Class (Module given)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'hve used spree paypal express extension on spree(https://github.com/spree/spree_paypal_express), got following error for rake db:migrate.

**Ruby 1.8.7 and rails 3.1.3**

> rake aborted!
>   superclass must be a Class (Module given)

```
/Users/kunalsupe/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `load_file'
/Users/kunalsupe/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/kunalsupe/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:455:in `load_file'
/Users/kunalsupe/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `require_or_load'
/Users/kunalsupe/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:489:in `load_missing_constant'
/Users/kunalsupe/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `const_missing'
/Users/kunalsupe/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:179:in `each'
/Users/kunalsupe/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:179:in `const_missing'
/Users/kunalsupe/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/bundler/gems/spree_paypal_express-6e6b553313c5/lib/spree_paypal_express/engine.rb:20
/Users/kunalsupe/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `call'
/Users/kunalsupe/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `execute_hook'
/Users/kunalsupe/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `run_load_hooks'
/Users/kunalsupe/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
/Users/kunalsupe/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
/Users/kunalsupe/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56
/Users/kunalsupe/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/Users/kunalsupe/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/kunalsupe/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `run_initializers'
/Users/kunalsupe/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/Users/kunalsupe/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/Users/kunalsupe/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
/Users/kunalsupe/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
/Users/kunalsupe/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
```

Is there any solution to this

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong version of this extension. Please check the extension's Version for the correct version to use with the version of Spree that you're using.

For example, with Spree 0.70.x you should be using [this ref.](https://github.com/spree/spree_paypal_express/blob/master/Versionfile#L2)

Your problem is caused by using a too-new version of the extension for the version of Spree that you're on.